# How to draw the graph of the optimised function in linear programming

Tags: graphing-functions, linear-programming

Ok, I don't know if I am just over thinking this, but I have been tearing my hair out trying to think about this. I have looked at plenty of linear programming examples and solutions online and I can't find anything that explains how the optimised function is drawn.

For example, there is a situation where you are trying to minimise the cost of potatoes and soybeans where $x_s$ is the amount of soybeans and $x_p$ is the amount of potatoes.

Soybeans cost twice the amount that potatoes do so we have a cost function of
$C = x_p + 2x_s$ which we are trying to minimize.

There are some other constraints involved which I understand how to derive:

- $2x_p + 3x_s \ge 12$
- $4x_p + x_s \ge 8$
- $x_p \ge 0 $ and $x_s \ge 0 $

The following graph is shown in the answer to the question where the blue line represents the cost function and the red star is the optimal solution (which I also know how to find once the cost function is drawn)

**What is the logic behind drawing the blue graph line from $C = x_p + 2x_s$?** (Sorry if I am just being really stupid but please explain it I need to sleep.)

[image: graph image]

Comment: The blue line is just a visualization of the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) of the objective function.

Comment: and it tells us that once the vertices of the (convex) feasible polytope are listed, finding the optimum is trivial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blue line is perpendicular to all the lines of the form $x_p+2x_s=c$ where $c$ is a constant, i.e. to the level sets of the cost function. So each point on it has a different cost, and the cost goes down as you move to the left. The slope of the blue line is $2$ because the slopes of the level sets of the cost function are all $-1/2$. So this graphical technique reduces the optimization question to "what is the leftmost point on the blue line such that if you draw the line perpendicular to the blue line through that point, there is a point on that line in the feasible region?"

This is a little bit of a weird way to do it, I think, but it does work.

Comment: I understand how to solve the problem with the line, I dont understand how I form the line in the first place just from the cost function alone.

Comment: @ρσݥzση It is the line with y-intercept 0 (which is essentially arbitrarily chosen) and which is perpendicular to the level sets of the cost function. These level sets are lines with slope $-1/2$, so the slope should be $2$, which it is.

Comment: Oh, I see thanks, I can't believe I have been staring at that for an hour and a half. My lecturer likes to do things in ways no one else seems to, it just means that when it comes to looking up what he did I don't really tend to find a clear answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A cost isoline is
$$
C = x_p + 2 x_s \quad (*) \iff \\
x_s = -\frac{1}{2} x_p + \frac{C}{2} \quad (F)
$$
We can rewrite $(*)$ as
$$
(1, 2) \cdot (x_p, x_s) = C \iff \\
(1/\sqrt{5}) \, (1,2) \cdot (x_p, x_s) =  C/\sqrt{5} \quad (N)
$$
which is the equation of an affine hyperplane (sounds complicated, but is just a line which needs not to include the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$) with unit normal 
$n = (1/\sqrt{5}) \, (1,2)$ and distance $C/\sqrt{5}$ to the origin.

That blue line is $\alpha \, n$ (for real numbers $\alpha$). 
The cost isolines run orthogonal to it, and have the distance $C/\sqrt{5}$ from the origin. The lower the (absolute value of the) cost, the closer to the origin runs the cost isoline.

[image: Normal, Cost lines, Feasible Region, Optimum]

The above image shows the constraints (half spaces in green colour), the feasible region (the region with the darkest green), the normal line $\alpha n$ (blue line), the cost isolines for $C=10$, $C=8$ and $C=6$ (black lines orthogonal to the blue line). Circles of distance with $r = 1$ and $r = 6/\sqrt{5}$ around the origin (purple circles). And finally the optimum with minimal cost (red dot).

Comment: Except the blue line has slope $2$, not $-1/2$.

Comment: It agrees in the way that I describe in my answer, but it does seem like a strange way to do it.

Comment: @ρσݥzση See the image I added and my answer for the equations of the cost isoline as function $x_s(x_p)$ and in normal form, see equations $(F)$ and $(N)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ be the slope of the cost function. Then the perpendicular line has slope $-1/a$. Along the perpendicular line the cost will grow or fall depending on which way you go.